# Another condition of calculating work

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, work

[image]Let's imagine that there is a box placed at the corner of a table, and I push it so that my applied force makes an angle of 30° from the table's surface.

The box would move and, due to the effect of the $x$-component of my force, it would fall making an incline from the corner of the table to the ground. And the y-component of displacement will be due to gravitational force.

So the work done by my force should be equal to the product of the $x$-component of my force and the displacement of the box along the $x$ axis. And similarly we can calculate the work done by the gravitational force. Is this correct?

Comment: when calculating work done by you , the x-component will be the distance through which you applied the force, once you let go , the work you did is -> K.E of the body.hope this helps

Comment: It will not fall along the incline unless there is an inclined plane attached to the table.

Comment: I, merely, stated the question on behalf of my imagination. And in imagination all is possible.

Comment: Talk to me on chat.

Comment: No, I think the situation is more complicated, or I do not understand what you mean. Talk to me on chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the work done by gravitational force as the product of its weight and y-displacement. If I have got your question right, the body is freely falling after the force tips it off the table. So the work done by your force will not be as you have written. 
It would've been correct if the force had been acting on the body throughout its displacement. Your force is just providing it some acceleration(and so some velocity) so that it tips off the table and falls. Its not acting for a finite non zero displacement.

Comment: I wrote there that the body is falling making an incline from corner of table to the ground.

Comment: is incline supposed to mean projectile motion and if you read my comment it might clear things up

Comment: But you had written that the body 'dropped' which created the confusion. Sorry

Comment: If the box make a displacement in the x-direction relative to the corner , then its "pushed" not dropped. you should try to edit question with an image or simple diagram if you want to be more clear i think . we maybe misunderstanding

Comment: I have added the picture; you can see.